# MYSQL - apply a where clause to only some fields

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this table in MYSQL:

```
Year    Type    Value  ID

0       0       5      1
2010    1       6      1
2011    1       4      1
2012    1       5      1
2013    1       7      1
2014    1       8      1
2015    1       5      1
0       0       6      2
2009    1       7      2
2010    1       4      2
2011    1       2      2
2012    1       8      2
2013    1       8      2
2014    1       5      2
```

I want to select the minimum and maximum year for each person (IDs 1 and 2), but I also want to select the value associated with type 0 for each person as well. Ideally this is what the query result would look like:

```
ID   MinYear    MaxYear    Type0Value
1    2010       2015       5
2    2009       2014       6
```

The query should look, I think, something like this...

```
select ID, 
(min(year) where type = 1) as MinYear, 
(max(year) where type = 1) as MaxYear,
(value where type = 0) as Type0Value
from table
group by ID
```

But this is obviously not correct SQL syntax. How do I do this?

Comment: what do you think about using self join??

Comment: Ah, totally forgot about that! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

strange table structure, but:

```
select
    _type0.id,
    _type0.value,
    _type1._min,
    _type1._max
from
    tbl as _type0
    inner join (
        select
            id,
            min(year) as _min,
            max(year) as _max
        from
            tbl
        where
            1 = type
        group by
            id
    ) as _type1 on
        _type0.id = _type1.id
where
    0 = _type0.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use inner join.
one half will handle the min and max, second half the type0value:

```
select a.minYear, a.maxYear, a.id, b.type0value from 
(select min(year) as minYear, max(year) as maxYear, id from table where id = 1 group by id) as a
inner join table as b on a.id = b.id 
where b.type = 0
```

Comment: i guess your answer is dupe , @underscore_d has provide the answer 9 minutes before your post with same logic

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo-code is actually pretty close.  You just need conditional aggregation:

```
select ID, 
       min(case when type = 1 then year end) as MinYear, 
       max(case when type = 1 then year end) as MaxYear,
       max(case when type = 0 then value end) as Type0Value
from table
group by ID;
```

If there could be multiple rows with `type = 0`, you might want `group_concat()` instead.